# running total starting from a date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get a running total as of a date. This is the data I have

| Date | transaction Amount | End of Week Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jan 1 | 5 | 100 |
| jan 2 | 3 | 100 |
| jan 3 | 4 | 100 |
| jan 4 | 3 | 100 |
| jan 5 | 1 | 100 |
| jan 6 | 3 | 100 |

I would like to find out what the daily end balance is. My thought is to get a running total from each day to the end of the week and subtract it from the end of week balance, like below

| Date | transaction Amount | Running total | End of Week Balance | Balance - Running total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| jan 1 | 5 | 19 | 100 | 86 |
| jan 2 | 3 | 14 | 100 | 89 |
| jan 3 | 4 | 11 | 100 | 93 |
| jan 4 | 3 | 7 | 100 | 96 |
| jan 5 | 1 | 4 | 100 | 97 |
| jan 6 | 3 | 3 | 100 | 100 |

I can use

`SUM(transactionAmount) OVER (Order by Date)`

to get a running total, is there a way to specify that I only want the total of transactions that have taken place after the date?

Comment: Jan 1 2021 was Friday. Be very careful and specific how you define "end of week" as that can complicate the logic you need. Conveniently your sample data does not span more than 7 days.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum()` as a window function, but accumulate in reverse:

```
select t.*,
       (end_of_week_balance -
        sum(transactionAmount) over (order by date desc)
       ) 
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have this example:

```
1> select i, sum(i) over (order by i) S from integers where i<10;
2> go
i           S
----------- -----------
          1           1
          2           3
          3           6
          4          10
          5          15
          6          21
          7          28
          8          36
          9          45
```

you can also do:

```
1> select i, sum(case when i>3 then i else 0 end) over (order by i) S from integers where i<10;
2> go
i           S
----------- -----------
          1           0
          2           0
          3           0
          4           4
          5           9
          6          15
          7          22
          8          30
          9          39
```